# Making my own "database" using Node and FS

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

So I'm trying to make a database, couple of function snippets that read, write or create X.json files. The way I imagined it to be is a DB folder, then within that folder bunch of username folders, and there, a bunch of files, like account.json, level.json, and so on... So each folder would keep users data, now, this is the code I managed to write so far, and it works.
But the problem is, on the FS docs, it says that using fs.stat to check for the existence of the file before reading/writing to it is a bad idea. I don't understand why tho, as that seems like the only way to do it before I keep asking questions, I'd like to paste my code here:

```
socket.on('play', (data) => {
    fs.stat(`db/${data.username}/account.json`, (error, result) => {
      if(!error) {
        fs.readFile(`db/${data.username}/account.json`, (error, result) => {
          if(error) {
            throw error;
          } else {
            const rawResult = JSON.parse(result);

            if(data.password == rawResult.password) {
              socket.emit('playResponse', {
                success: true,
                msg: 'Login Succesfull'
              });
            } else {
              socket.emit('playResponse', {
                success: false,
                msg: 'Wrong Password!'
              });
            }
          }
        });
      } else if(error.code == 'ENOENT') {
        socket.emit('playResponse', {
          success: false,
          msg: 'Account not found'
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

I haven't written a general function that does this for me, because I figured that the code above is a mess right now. So, why is it a bad practice to check for the existence of the file (fs.stat) before writing/reading from them? I guess I could do something with the error I get from the readFile function and omit the `fs.stat` function, but whenever readFile function comes across a folder that doesn't exist, my server just crashes.

I'm not very experienced with Node, so the code above is probably absolute nonsense. That's why I'm here!

How can I make my server not crash if the readFile comes across a non-existent folder, but instead just emit the "Account not Found" through socket.io? If I put that emit code there, my server just crashes anyway.

I would just go with MongoDB or something, but I have a loooot of free time and doing stuff like this is very fun for me. > Is using a DB like mongo like more secure, or do people do it so they don't have to waste time writing their own DB?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the problem is, on the FS docs, it says that using fs.stat to check for the existence of the file before reading / writing to it is bad idea. I don't understand why tho

The reason is mentioned on the deprecated `fs.exists` docs:

> Using fs.exists() to check for the existence of a file before calling fs.open(), fs.readFile() or fs.writeFile() is not recommended. Doing so introduces a race condition, since other processes may change the file's state between the two calls. Instead, user code should open/read/write the file directly and handle the error raised if the file does not exist.

---

> How can I make my server not crash if the readFile comes across a non existent folder, but instead just emit the "Account not Found" through socket.io?

You don't handle the errors properly. As an example you throw an error in your `.readFile` callback but your code leaves the error unhandled, that will "crash" your application. You could either wrap your code with a `try/catch` block or use promises. Promises provide nice APIs to handle errors in your application. Node.js v10.0.0 introduces [promise-wrapped APIs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api) for `fs` module APIs.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fsPromises = fs.promises;
fsPromises.readFile(`db/${data.username}/account.json`).then(error => {
   // the file exists and readFile could read it successfully! 
   // you can throw an error and the next `catch` handle catches the error
}).catch(error => {
  // there was an error
});
```

You can also use the APIs with `try/catch` and `await`:

```
try {
  const content = await fsPromises.readFile(`db/${data.username}/account.json`);
  // the file exists and readFile could read it successfully!
} catch(error) {
 // handle the possible error
}
```

If using node v10.0.0 is not an option you can use a npm package that provides promised-wrapped fs APIs like [`fs-extra`](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra) or [`draxt`](https://ramhejazi.github.io/draxt):

```
// using draxt
const $ = require('draxt');
const File = $.File;

const file = new File(`db/${data.username}/account.json`);
file.read('utf8').then(contents => {
   // the file exists and readFile could read it successfully!
}).catch(error => {
  // handle the possible error
});
```

Comment: Neato, I didn't think promises worked with fs. I remember trying to figure out how promises worked for like a whole month but I never used them, not realizing their purpose. Is this only with Node 10, if it is, do you maybe know when is the Node 10 LTS being released? My game is far from over, so I could give it a couple of months wait, I guess. Is it a big deal if I use the "unstable" version for now?

And holy cow, with promises the code looks so clean. I wouldn't use try /catch with async/await as I don't really fully understand that yet. I'll stick with promises for now.

Comment: All right dude, that was more answers than I was looking for, god bless! I guess I'll just download node 10 right away and give it a spin

Comment: @MiloSx7 As a note, you can also promisify the fs APIs  yourself.

Comment: I don't know if I want to go "that deep", as my Node knowledge is very basic. But I will probably go back to this thread and read your answer many times in the next year, like I do with most of my questions here, until I get to understand everything you posted... Well, all in due time :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the file could be deleted betweent the time where you did got response the `stat` call and the `readFile` call.

The recommend way is to do call the `readFile` and the check for the error code in the callback of the `readFile`. For the callback based version this would look that way:

```
socket.on('play', (data) => {
  fs.readFile(`db/${data.username}/account.json`, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      if (error.code === 'ENOENT') {
        socket.emit('playResponse', {
          success: false,
          msg: 'Account not found'
        })
      } else {
        // throw the error if you really want to exit the application for unknown errors
        throw error
      }
    } else {
      const rawResult = JSON.parse(result)

      if (data.password === rawResult.password) {
        socket.emit('playResponse', {
          success: true,
          msg: 'Login Succesfull'
        })
      } else {
        socket.emit('playResponse', {
          success: false,
          msg: 'Wrong Password!'
        })
      }
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Oh.... so `throw error` closes the app........ Gee wiz looks like I skipped a lot of documentation haha. Well, thanks for taking your time to fix my original method, although I've already decided to go with promises. I can't believe I fail to understand basic stuff like this

Comment: @MiloSx7 I don't want to suggest that you should use classic callbacks. In an environment where you can use `await`/`async` I most of the time would also prefere to use Promises. I posted it so that you can see where how to solv it in the way you originally tried to. And Promises can also close your application if you don't handle their rejection.

Comment: I am aware of that. Promises and async await are just so very confusing to me, and for the life of me can't understand them completely. Just when I think I do, I realize I actually still have no clue. So I guess I'll scratch the promises for now and go with this solution first. And maybe try to build a snippet function so I can have some cleaner code. I'll come back here multiple times until I just understand fully what undefined had suggested. Callbacks are so confusing....