# Node "database" using promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

So I recently posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52236967/making-my-own-database-using-node-and-fs) and undefined had suggested me use Node 10 and fs with built-in promises. Now I wanted to go that route, but I really didn't understand promises. I think it finally clicked in my head, but I'm still not sure whether I'm doing it the right way. I remember trying to understand promises before to use them with mongojs, only to learn that promises don't work with it, or something. I'm confused? Is there only a specific type functions that I can put into promises, or how does that work. However, here is the code for now, on Node 8. I don't know if this will work, if fs, like mongojs, doesn't work with promises, or whatever... o.O

```
socket.on('play', (data) => {
  const iPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(`db/${data.username}/account.json`, (error, result) => {
      if(error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        resolve(result);
      }
    });
  });

  iPromise.then((result) => {
    const rawResult = JSON.parse(result);

    if(data.password === rawResult.password) {
      socket.emit('playResponse', {
        success: true,
        msg: 'Login Succesfull'
      });
    } else {
      socket.emit('playResponse', {
        success: false,
        msg: 'Wrong Password!'
      });
    }
  }).catch((error) => {
    if(error.code === 'ENOENT') {
      socket.emit('playResponse', {
        success: false,
        msg: 'Account not found'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

The point is, I just want to understand how promises work for now. I don't understand why I'm still stuck with callbacks, it's been a while now and It is still very confusing sometimes :\

Comment: Promises still require callbacks to execute code when they are fulfilled or rejected. The benefit of promises is you can chain the arbitrarily without having to keep nesting callbacks.

Comment: The more I look at the code I've just written right now the more I realize it really makes no sense. But, the thing is, I hope the logic of promises itself is correct. That would mean I'm on the correct path

Comment: I have updated my code now, it should be more clear of what I'm trying to achieve. I missed the most important part....

Comment: Yep, that's the way you would manually "promisify" a function with a callback. And you can do it with literally any function with a callback. Mongojs might not natively support promises, but no reason why you can't wrap it in a promise. As an aside, if you're working with native node.js functions you can often use the built-in [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, that's the answer I was looking for. Have a nice day!